# awk use a command line variable

Tags: variables, command-line, awk

`awk -F, -f awkfile.awk -v mysearch="search term"`

I am trying to use the above command from terminal and use search as the search term in the `awk` program.  My `awk` program runs perfectly fine while actually assigning the search term inside of the program but I am wondering how to get the variable search to be used?

example of the line it's used at `if($j ~ /mysearch/){`, this does not work at setting the search term, but actually searching for the string `mysearch`.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the slashes:

```
$j ~ mysearch
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but I suggest to write a bash script, which takes in the search term, replace that search term in the awk script, then run the script. For example:

```
$ cat dosearch.sh
sed "s/XXX/$1/" awktemplate.awk > awkfile.awk
awk -f awkfile.awk data.txt

$ cat awktemplate.awk
{
    j = 1
    if ($j ~ /XXX/) {
        # Do something, such as
        print "Found:", $0
    }
}

$ cat data.txt
foo here
bar there
xyz everywhere

$ ./dosearch.sh foo
Found: foo here

$ ./dosearch.sh bar
Found: bar there
```

In the above example, the awk template contains "XXX" as a search term, the bash script replaces that search term with the first parameter, then invoke awk on the modified script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input
tinky-winky
dipsy
laa-laa
noo-noo
po

$ teletubby='po'

$ awk -v "regexp=$teletubby" '$0 ~ regexp' input
po
```

Note that *anything* could go into the shell-variable,
even a full-blown regexp, e.g `^d.*y`. Just make sure to use single-quotes
to prevent the shell from doing any expansion.